# laravel excel how do i remove bullet when i do getcell

Tags: excel, laravel

```
Excel::load($path, function($reader) {

    $sheet = $reader->getSheetByName('nameofsheet');

    $cellvalue = $sheet->getCell('B10'); //cell with a bullet (bullet and text of cell)

    $echo $cellvalue;  //display (ÂŸ text of cell) display ÂŸ instead of bullet and i don't want this character


});
```

Comment: how do i remove bullet please ?  
thanks for answers